# How to highlight all previously deleted text after an undelete

Tags: vim, find, match, highlight

I often use a command or script to delete text and after I do an undelete (u) I want to see what has been previously deleted by the command/script.

Is it possible to highlight the previous deleted text when use the undelete command?
(or even better match the previous deleted text in a find "/" command)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just deleted some text using `d`, you can use `/<CTRL-R>"` to match the text you just deleted (even if you just undid the delete with `u`).

This won't work if the deleted text contains newlines or regex meta-characters (like `\` or `[`). If that's likely, try:

```
/\V<CTRL-R>=substitute(substitute(getreg('"'), "[\\/]", '\\\0', 'g'), "\n", '\\n', "g")
```

- `\V` - very nomagic - turns off most regex meta-characters
- `<CTRL-R>=` - insert the evaluation of a vim expression
- `substitute(..., "\n", '\\n', "g")` - escape all the newlines in the given string
- `substitute(..., "[\\/]", '\\\0', 'g')` - escape all slashes and backslashes in the given string
- `getreg('"')` - get the contents of the `"` register, which contains the most recently yanked and/or deleted text

This is a bit wordy, so if you find yourself needing to do it often, you can bind it to a command in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
" use ,/ in normal mode to match the most recently deleted or yanked text
nmap ,/ /\V<C-R>=substitute(substitute(getreg('"'), "[\\/]", '\\\0', 'g'), "\n", '\\n', "g")<CR><CR><CR>
```

Comment: @rampion, tnx, I tried the code `\V...`  It sometimes works and sometimes not. Did I do something wrong? P.e. I deleted 3 rows using this code `g/\%3l.\|\%5l.\|\%6l./d_` but it isn't highlighted after an "undo"

Comment: @Remonn: Whoops, typo.  Try again?

Comment: There was also a problem with my code `g/../d_`  --> I deleted it to the black hole. Do you know how to delete multiple lines with search match (`g/'search'/d`) and put it in the `"` register? the code g/'search'/d puts only 1 line to the register.

Comment: @Remonn: I would append it to a named register instead of using the `"` register. Something like this should work: `:let @a=""` then execute your command, `g/pattern/d A`. This will delete the lines into register `a` but append to `a` instead of overwriting.

Answer (score 4):

How about taking the diff from of one state of the file and compare to another?

```
:command! -nargs=0 DiffLastChange  exe "norm! u" | vert new | set bt=nofile | r # | 0d _ | diffthis | wincmd p | exe "norm! \<c-r>" | diffthis
```

Now you can just run `DiffLastChange` to see a diff of the last change to the file.

Explanation:

- `exe "norm! u"` undo the last change in the current buffer
- `vert new` vertically split a new buffer
- `set bt=nofile` change the buffer type to a scratch buffer
- `r #` read the contents from the alternate file i.e. the buffer we started out with
- `0d _` clean up the new buffer by removing the blank line at the top into the black hole register
- `diffthis` mark the current buffer to be a part of the diff
- `wincmd p` switch to the last buffer (back to the buffer we started out with)
- `exe "norm! \<c-r>"` execute a redo to restore the original buffers state
- `diffthis` mark the original buffer to be apart of the diff

After you are done I recommend executing `:diffoff!` to turn off both diffs.

Regrettably this command in its present state can not handle unsaved buffers as `:read #` will read in a file. The solution is to copy the contents of the buffer into a named register and then paste it into the scratch buffer. Sadly this will clobber a named register. Refactorting the code out into a function will give more flexibility and allow the use of a variable to save the contents of the register (and register type) and restore the register at the end.

```
function! DiffLastChange(...)
  let a = @a
  let at = getregtype('a')
  let c = a:0 == 1 ? a:1 : 1
  let ft = &ft
  try
    exe "norm! " . c . "u"
    sil %y a
    vert new
    set bt=nofile
    exe "set ft=" . ft
    sil pu a
    0d _
    diffthis
    wincmd p
    exe "norm! " . c . "\<c-r>"
    diffthis
  finally
    call setreg('a', a, at)
  endtry
endfunction
command! -nargs=? DiffLastChange call DiffLastChange(<f-args>)
```

In addition to fixing the unsaved buffer problems and clobbering issues, I have added the ability to go further back in history via a command argument e.g. `:DiffLastChange 3`. The command also sets the scratch buffer's filetype to the same as the original buffers so syntax highlighting will be turned on for that buffer.

For a much more robust solution for seeing the differences between parts of history in a buffer I agree with Christian Brabandt and suggest [Gundo](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3304) or [histwin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2932). For more information on Gundo, see this [vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/undo-branching-and-gundo-vim/).

For more help see:

```
:h diffthis
:h diffoff
:h wincmd
:h 'bt'
:h :r
:h :d
```

Comment: I will keep your solution also. Nice to know. Thanks Peter.

Comment: Peter, I receive many times this error: E499: Empty file name for '%' or '#', only works with ":p:h": r #  --> I checked a bit on the net but can't find out how to resolve this error

Comment: @Remonn: I get that error too when the file does not have a filename, aka has not been saved. I will update my answer with a version that does not suffer from such a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try the histwin or Gundo plugin. It lets you diff all undo branches and shows also shows a unified diff for the differences in the preview window.

Comment: Gundo needs python 2.4 support and gvim 7.3 hasn't python 2.4+ support. I already use the histwin plugin (nice plugin, you're the author isn't it?). I can't find out how to highlight the differences in the text. I find the solution of Peter very easy to apply and I like that it doesn't use the diffthis command.

Comment: Yes, I am the author. The histwin plugin can't really display the differences, but pressing 'U' on an entry should display a unified diff in the preview window, while pressing 'D' should give you similar to Peters suggesion show you a diff of both buffer states.

Comment: sorry, I mean "the solution of rampion" is easy to apply and doesn't use the diffthis command. Thanks for your ulterior info about the plugin.

Comment: BTW: histwin v0.22 can indicate added/changed/deleted lines by using the :ID command